# When would I use positional arguments for my Python program?

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I'm creating a Python program/utility that I want others to be able to use.

Currently it takes arguments when launched, for example

```
python main.py 123456 "joe"
```

I've noticed in many places that people pass arguments to their Python app using positional arguments like

```
python main.py 123456 --"joe"
```

What is the difference and advantage of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it the wrong way round, the first example was positional, the second was more like a named argument, although you might usually expect to see something more like `--file="joe"`. The reason for named arguments is usually to allow defaults to be taken when there are many arguments, without having to type all of the arguments that you don't care about. Positional arguments work well when there are very few of them, and they are always needed.